# cannot create database using rake and ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rake

I am using ruby and sinatra with activerecord and rake (no rails).  I have the following config.yml file in my db directory (I left out production).

**config.yml**

```
development:
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/development.sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

When I run rake db:create or rake db:setup, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: []
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:109:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**RakeFile**:

```
# Rakefile

require './app'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
#require 'rake'
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem 'sinatra-flash'
gem 'sinatra-redirect-with-flash'
gem 'rake'

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem "tux"
end

group :production do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: as a best practice, remove gem 'sqlite3' from under development, and production and just stick it at the end of your other gems just under gem 'rake'

Comment: I had different databases but just put sqlite in production when trying to solve the issue

Comment: any idea on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: did you make sure your run bundle install?

Comment: also make sure that you keep database configurations in config/database.yml not config.yml

Comment: I ran bundle install as well as copied the config.yml to database.yml - no solution. Am I missing any config files or commands?

Comment: I don't want to give you a misleading answer as I'm not familiar with sinatra; however, here is an example of a rails4 sinatra app using sqlite3. You can check the app directory structure https://github.com/qrohlf/hackathon-starter-sinatra

Answer (score 1):

Database configuration should be in `config/database.yml`, not in `db/config.yml`